# Prove unbiasedness for $T(X_1,...,X_n) = X_1$ with $X_1 \sim Bin(1,p)$ and $X_i$ i.i.d.

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I have $X_1,...,X_n$ i.i.d. random variables with $X_i \sim Bin(1,p)$, given the estimator $T(X_1,...,X_n) = X_1$ I want to show that $T$ is a biased estimator.
If I try to I get this result: $E(X_1) = p$ since $Bin(1,p)$'s mean is $p$.
Since the random variables $X_i$ are identically distributed doesn't that mean that the estimator is unbiased since all of them have a mean of $p$?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to estimate.

Comment: I'm trying to estimate the parametric function $\tau(p) = p$

Comment: What is $\tau$?

Comment: since $\tau$ is the identity I don't think it's important, in german statistics it's "parametrische Funktion" I don't know if it's really a "parametric function", its the same as  $\psi$ here: https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-meant-by-a-parametric-function-in-statistical-inference

Comment: Are you actually just trying to estimate the value of $p$?

Comment: Yes it seems so, now that I look at it again my question seems silly since $X_1$ should be an unbiased estimator for $p$ right? Would $\overline X$ be another unbiased estimator for $p$?

Comment: Yes, $X_1$ and $\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}$ both have mean $p$ (so they are both unbiased estimators of $p$) but the latter has better mean squared error.

Comment: Thanks alot, as soon as I'll get 15 points you'll get my upvotes, sorry that I was so confused, had notes that said "biased"